# JS Selenium findElements won't resolve

Tags: javascript, selenium, promise, webdriver

I am wondering why this code never resolves to success or failure.

```
driver.findElements(By.id(eid)).then(
      function (ret) {
        console.log("Success");
        return !!ret.length;
      }, function (err) {
        console.log("Failure");
      }
);
```

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_WebDriver.html#findElements

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js#L1049

Comment: From the code, all things is ok.  Can you give a small but runable the code snippet, so we can try on our side.  And did you try above code on other website?

Comment: I don't think that there is another code needed in order to test it. It should always print out Success or Failure even if the element is found or not.

Comment: Is possible some error had occur before above code? Or try another version of  selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that you shouldn't rely on callbacks and you should rather use promises.

So in my case, it would look like:

```
let ret = driver.findElements(By.id(eid));
console.log("Success");
return !!ret.length;
```

What do you think guys?

Comment: This article made things clearer: http://testerstories.com/2016/03/webdriver-in-javascript-with-promises/

Answer (score 0):

I run below code on my chrome, it worked find. I can get 'find h2 count: 7'.
I installed selenium-webdriver@3.5.0

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub')
    .build();

driver.get('https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver');

driver.sleep(5000);

driver.findElements(By.css('h2')).then(function(eles) {
    console.log('find h2 count: ' + eles.length);
    return !!eles.length;
}, function(err) {
    console.log('error: ' + err);
    return err;
});
```